# Must run a SQLPlus query in bat file, can't get query to append the query results a txt file using the .BAT file

Tags: oracle, batch-file, echo, sqlplus

I know this is something minor I'm screwing up. **I didn't write the SQL -it's as is - just the .BAT file.**  I have to run it using a .BAT file as there's more stuff that happens afterwards.

I have a query. It's supposed to insert a bunch of values from different tables into a temp table, then return all four fields separated by commas, and no header row. It works like it's supposed to. I tried to anonymize it, so it might look weird.

SQL File Name: c:\Directory\BA_ExportAll.sql

---

THESE TWO LINES are at the top of the query and I don't know why they aren't properly appearing to be in the sql query itself.

> START /data/admin/connect.sql
>
> START today.sql
>
> ```
>   INSERT INTO
>           My_Table_TMP
>   SELECT
>           'A',
>           'Sequence',
>           AUX.P_ID,
>           NULL
>   FROM
>           (
>           SELECT
>                   P_ID
>           FROM
>                   Table1
>           WHERE
>                   feedDate = (SELECT MAX(feedDate) FROM Table1)
>           MINUS
>           SELECT
>                   P_ID
>           FROM
>                   Table2
>           WHERE
>                   objstate NOT LIke 'C%'
>           ) AUX
>   ;
>      --Then a bunch of other queries that build the temp table  
>   
>   COMMIT;
>   
>   
>   SET COLSEP ''
>   SET SPACE 0
>   SET LIN 150
>   SET PAGES 0
>   SET VERIFY OFF
>   SET FEEDBACK OFF
>   SET ECHO OFF;
>   
>   COLUMN Value FORMAT A11
>   
>   SPOOL segment_after.&today 
>   
>   SELECT
>           flag || ',',
>           segment || ',',
>           value || ',' as value,
>           '"' || description || '"'
>   FROM
>           My_Table_TMP
>   ;
>   SPOOL OFF;
>   EXIT;
> ```

---

So far, so good.

Now, the .BAT file.

---

> cd C:\Directory\
>
> sqlplus /nolog @BA_ExportAll.sql
>
> ECHO c:\Directory\BA_ExportAll.sql >> "c:\Directory\BA_HeaderTest.txt"

The .BAT file will eventually kick off an email script and some other stuff.

---

This just appends the actual line "c:\Directory\BA_ExportAll.sql" into the "c:\Directory\BA_HeaderTest.txt" text file. I have googled and checked here, obviously, over and over and can't find any similar questions. I'm assuming it's completely simple!!

Thanks, all!

Comment: When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will close if a syntax-error is found or the script runs to completion. You should instead [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any (error) messages will be displayed. Alternatively, add a `pause` statement after the `sqlplus` line. I've no idea what the `/nolog` switch does - perhaps it do no logging at all...

Comment: Yes, I run it from opening the command prompt as administrator. No errors are returned. It shows the query and the results, and It appends data to the file, but not with the actual data, just the name of the SQL query.

Comment: @Magoo -- _" I've no idea what the /nolog switch does - perhaps it do no logging at all."_   The /nolog switch tells sqlplus to not attempt a logon when starting up.  The assumption is that the logon will be requested at the sqlplus command line or by the sql script.  This is documented . . .

Answer (score 1):

```
sqlplus /nolog @BA_ExportAll.sql >> "c:\Directory\BA_HeaderTest.txt"
```

should append any console output to the text file.

Your `echo` line merely appends the literal `c:\Directory\BA_ExportAll.sql`  to the text file

```
TYPE c:\Directory\BA_ExportAll.sql >> "c:\Directory\BA_HeaderTest.txt"
```

would append the contents of the `.sql` file to the `.txt` file.

---

To skip a number of lines of the `sqlplus` output, try

```
(
 for /f "skip=ndelims=" %%b in ('sqlplus /nolog @BA_ExportAll.sql') do echo %%b
)>> "c:\Directory\BA_HeaderTest.txt"
```

Placing parentheses around a command buffers the output so the file is not perpetually opened and closed (I believe).

for /f reads the output of the command in quotes line-by-line. It has many options - see `for /?` from the prompt and many, many applications on SO for documentation & ideas. The `delims=` option causes all of the line to be applied to `token 1` and appears in `%%b`. The `skip=n` option skips the initial `n` lines.

Comment: Thank you!! It's 99% working now. When it appends, it appends all of this:

Comment: ...and the 1% not working is...?

Comment: It was too long for one comment.

Comment: OK, was able to get it to just append:    *******SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Mon Apr 11 08:57:28 2022

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected.

User altered.

Connected. and then the query results, and the line about disconnecting.

Comment: BAT file is now `cd C:\Directory\

sqlplus /nolog @BA_ExportAll.sql >> "c:\Directory\BA_HeaderTest.txt"`

Comment: Modified SQL and removed the ECHO ON line.

Comment: You'd possibly need to change the `echo on` line in your batch (should be the first line) to `@echo off` which will stop batch from showing the commands as they are executed. That line doesn't appear in your posted `.bat` though. Can't see what you now have a problem with.

Comment: Hmm? I don't know where to put it. The bat file is now just two lines cd C:\BankAmerica\

sqlplus /nolog @BA_ExportAll.sql >> "c:\BankAmerica\BA_HeaderTest.txt"

Comment: `@echo off` would usually be the first line in any batch file. @echo off turns off command-echoing. @thiscommandline turns off echoing of thiscommandline. `@echo on` turns command-line echoing back on again. You'd normally set `echo`ing on for debugging , then off when the batch has been debugged.

Comment: '@ECHO OFF

cd C:\BankAmerica\

sqlplus /nolog @BA_ExportAll.sql >> "c:\BankAmerica\BA_HeaderTest.txt"'

Comment: Still shows commands in the actual .txt file. SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Mon Apr 11 11:28:38 2022

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected.

User altered.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you'd like to **append** result of that `SELECT` statement into a file which already contains some data.

If that's so, then it is the `SPOOL` command you should modify (the last `ECHO` won't do any good):

```
SPOOL segment_after.&today APPEND
```

i.e.

```
  ...
  SET FEEDBACK OFF
  SET ECHO OFF;
  
  COLUMN Value FORMAT A11
  
  SPOOL segment_after.&today APPEND 
  
  SELECT ...
  FROM ...;
  SPOOL OFF;
  EXIT;
```

Comment: I don't think you saw the second part. The spool is in a SQL file. There's a .BAT file that runs the query. It has the echo in it.